# Multi Tenant Access to Microsoft Graph API's with single app registration?

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I have multiple mailboxes with multiple tenants. I am wondering if I can access the graph API's through a single app registration?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could do that.

[Register your Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) app as multi-tenant. You need to choose "Accounts in any orgnizational directory".

[image]

And you need to implement [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) and use Application permission to access the mailboxes. The most important thing is to [get administrator consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#3-get-administrator-consent) for each tenant.

We assume that this app is registered in TenantA. Now you want to access mailbox in TenantB. Then you should do admin consent like this: access the following url in a broswer.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantB}/adminconsent
?client_id={cliend id of registered app in TenantA}
&state=12345
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri of registered app in TenantA}
```

Log in with an admin account of TenantB to do the admin consent for TenantB.

After that you could [Get an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#4-get-an-access-token) for TenantB to access your mailbox in TenantB.